# set minimum RSA key length to be used for validating the certificate received from the server

Tags: java, android, ssl

In connection opened by Android application how to you set the minimum RSA key length to be used for validating the certificate received from the server ?

i.e. the connection should be rejected if key length of the server certificate is 1024 when you set min to be 2048.

I need to do it for multiple types of connections :

1. HTTPUrlConnection
2. All connections made by WebView
3. Connections made by UnboundID LDAP library. This takes input of a regular SSLSocketFactory so if there is a generic solution at SSLSocketFactory level then it should work for this as well